# How to implement FLXHR with JQuery for crossdomain interaction

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery, FLXHR for getting the data from Cross Browser.

Below is the sample **jquery code:**

```
        // set up the domain that we're going to call and tell flXHR not to try to parse the response as XML..
 $.flXHRproxy.registerOptions("http://staging/", {xmlResponseText:false});

 // set flXHR as the default XHR object used in jQuery AJAX requests
 $.ajaxSetup({transport:'flXHRproxy'});


 $.ajax({  
        type:"POST",        
        url: "http://staging/Login.aspx",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: str, 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(result)
        { 
             // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  
        } 

    });
```

In above code I am using JQuery and Flash to have cross browser interaction, above code is working fine, with **http://staging/Login.aspx**, however when I am going for **https://staging/Login.aspx** (HTTPS) authentication its giving me error **(NS_ERROR_PROXY_CONNECTION_REFUSED)**.

Please suggest how to get rid of this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved my issue with given below code changes.

I took the help of below articles.

1) http://www.offshootinc.com/blog/2010/03/12/cross-domain-scripting-with-jquery-and-flxhr/

2) http://tek-insight.blogspot.com/2010/05/cross-domain-ajax-request-proxy-json.html

3) http://flxhr.flensed.com

We have to download plugin from **FLXHR website** and have to copy the contents of **"Deploy"** folder in same location where all the **Javascript** are kept.

Below is sample code of **crossdomain.xml** which we need to copy on the root directory of your website.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"  secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Here goes **JQuery Code:**

```
    var ajaxGatewayUrl = "https://staging/login/login.aspx";
    var loadPolicyURL = "https://staging/crossdomain.xml"

    // set flXHR as the default XHR object used in jQuery AJAX requests
    $.ajaxSetup({transport:'flXHRproxy'});
    // set up the domain that we're going to call and tell flXHR not to try to parse the response as XML..
    $.flXHRproxy.registerOptions(ajaxGatewayUrl,{xmlResponseText:false,loadPolicyURL:loadPolicyURL});

 //Submitting the form
$("#loginDetails > form").submit(function()
{
     //Hiding the Login button
    $("#loginButton").hide();

    //Showing the ajax loading image
    $("#ajaxloading").show();

    // 'this' refers to the current submitted form  
    var str = $(this).serialize();   
    // -- Start AJAX Call --

    $.ajax({ 
        type:"POST",        
        url: ajaxGatewayUrl,  // Send the login info to this page
        data:str, 
        cache:false,
        dataType: "json",        
        success: function(result)
        {  
             // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  

            if(result.Response!='NULL')
            {     

                     $('.validateTips').hide();
                    var login_response = '<div id="logged_in">' +
                     '<div style="width: 350px; float: left; margin-left: 80px;">' + 
                     '<div style="width: 40px; float: left;">' +
                     '<img style="margin: 22px 0px 10px 0px;" align="absmiddle" src="system/images/ajax-loader.gif">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div style="margin: 24px 0px 0px 10px; float: right; width: 300px;">'+ 
                     "You are successfully logged in! <br /> Please wait while you're redirected...</div></div>";  

                    $('#loginButton').hide();
                    $('#closeBtn').hide();
                    $('#divMember').text(result.FirstName +' '+ result.LastName);
                    $('#spnSkywardsNo').text(result.ActiveCardNo);
                    $('#spnTierStatus').text(result.MemberShipTier);
                    $("#ui-dialog-title-skywardsLogin").text(getDataFromResourceFile('pleaseWait'));

                    $('#divSuccessLogin').html(login_response);
                    $('#divSuccessLogin').show();
                    $('#loginDetails').hide();



                    // After 3 seconds redirect the 
                    setTimeout(closeDialog, 3000); 
              }
            else// ERROR?
             {  
                 var login_response = getDataFromResourceFile('InvalidUsername');
                 $('.validateTips').html(login_response);
             }
        }, 
        error:function(request, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  

            $('.validateTips').html("Some Issue with requested URL");
        } 

    });  

    // -- End AJAX Call --

    return false; 
});
```

Please have a look to above implementation and suggest for good inputs.

Comment: I was able to do the same without explicitly specifying where to find crossdomain.xml (it found it on its own in the root) - have you tested without explicitly specifying where to find this file?