# Giving Access Denied error ini IE7/8 and NS_ERROR_PROXY_CONNECTION_REFUSED in firefox

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery, FLXHR for Cross browser authentications.

I have implemented JQuery FLXHR to my project, all is working fine till I am using the same domain for example if my login page is (http://staging/login/loginpopup.aspx) and its sending the request to (http://staging/login/login.aspx) for user authentication it works great, just when I change it for HTTPS request, I mean when I send to HTTPS request (https://staging/login/login.aspx) from HTTP it is giving error "text/html (NS_ERROR_PROXY_CONNECTION_REFUSED)" in firefox and "Access Denied" error in IE7 and IE8.

If I see in **Response Header** in HTTPFOX it shows below content.

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
Via 1.1 DXBMIPX12
Proxy-Authenticate  Negotiate
Kerberos
NTLM
Connection  close
Proxy-Connection    close
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Type    text/html
Content-Length  727
```

Please suggest what I am missing or what changes are required to fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is resolved with example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533281/how-to-implement-jquery-and-flxhr-for-crossdomain-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

If your sending an ajax request from http to https then it is considered cross domain thus falling foul of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Firefox 3.5+ has a feature to enable cross domain calls as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control), however this is not a cross browser solution (yet).